# I would like to know if the following code is 'good'

Tags: c++

I would like a serious, blunt and cold judgement on this code.  Would it be considered 'good' code?  In general, is it well written?  Is the design reasonable?

```
#include <iostream>   // C++ IO library code to include.
#include <string>     // C++ string functions.
using namespace std ; // Use standard C++ names for functions.


//====== class declaration.

class Tpacket_list
{public: // functions that are available to code outside the class.
    // put the command line into the list.
    Tpacket_list(int param_index, string param) ;  
    void print_list() ; // print the list.
    Tpacket_list* find( string target) ;
    int    tell_id() ;
    string tell_payload() ;

 protected:                //  Data in a class is normally hidden from other code.
    string payload ;       // C++ strings are classes so this is aggregation.
    int id ;               // Such strings are more powerful and easier to use
    Tpacket_list *next ;   //   than the older C string routines, also slower!
} ;


Tpacket_list *list_head ;  // Start of linked list, set to 1st item.
Tpacket_list *work_ptr ;   // Work pointer to work along list.

//====== Class Body =========================================================

//------ Constructor gets called when the class is created. It puts in the
//       payload and sets up the chain of pointers.All this is hideen from
//       the user of the class.
Tpacket_list::Tpacket_list(int param_index, string param) 
{//--- save information for this parameter.
   id = param_index ;
   payload = param ;
   cout << "    Adding parameter # " << id << ", value = " << payload << endl ;
 //--- form list.
   next = list_head ;
   list_head = this ;
}

//------ Print the list.  Note how the function calls the print_list function
//       in the next item in the link list.
//       Function prints from the current link list item to the end.
void Tpacket_list::print_list()
{//---
   cout << "    id = " << id << ",  payload = " << payload << ", length " << payload.length() << " characters."<< endl ;
   if ( next != NULL) // if there is a next item, get it to print itself.
     next->print_list() ;
}


//------ Find item in the list.
Tpacket_list* Tpacket_list::find( string target)
{//---
   if ( payload == target)
      return ( this) ;          // return pointer to current object.
   if ( next == NULL)
      return( NULL) ;           // end of list, not match, return NULL.
   //--- if got here there is a valid next.
   return( next->find( target)) ;
}

//------ Tell of internal data.
int    Tpacket_list::tell_id() 
 { return( id) ;
 }

string Tpacket_list::tell_payload()
 { return( payload) ;
 }

//====== Start program here =================================================

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) // argc = number strings on command line.
                                 // argv is array of strings each holding 
                                 //   a parameter.

{//--- Initialize link list with command parameters.
   cout << endl << "  Form link list of command line parameters." << endl ;
   list_head = NULL ;
   int i = 1 ;
   while ( i < argc)
    { new Tpacket_list(i, argv[i]) ;
      i++ ;
    }

 //--- print out the list.
   cout << "  Print paramters from head of list the end of list." << endl ;
   if ( list_head != NULL)
        list_head->print_list() ;
   else cout << "   List is empty." << endl ;

 //--- search for parameters
   cout << "  Find first 0 parameter (working last to first parameter, list head to tail)." << endl ;
   Tpacket_list *found ;
   if ( list_head != NULL)
     { found = list_head->find("0") ;
       if ( found != NULL)
            cout << "    Found target on parameter # " << found->tell_id()  << endl ;
       else cout << "    No \"0\" found." << endl ;
     }

   cout << endl ;
   return(0) ;
}
```

P.S. It's not my code, it's actually the lecturer's.

Comment: Your question title is no good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For overall quality, I'd give this about a 2 or maybe a 3 (on a scale of 1-10). Honestly, even 3 is being pretty generous though.

```
#include <iostream>   // C++ IO library code to include.
#include <string>     // C++ string functions.
using namespace std ; // Use standard C++ names for functions.
```

`using namespace std;` is generally frowned upon. There are reasons for `using` a namespace, but doing it globally like this (especially with the `std`namespace) is just a lousy idea.

```
//====== class declaration.
```

I'm sort of split on this one. On one hand, vacuous comments like this are generally worse than useless. At the same time, given that it's written exclusively for teaching, it may be excusable to include a few things we'd normally reject, describing basics of how C++ works. This would be a no-no in real code, but under the circumstances it's understandable and (I guess) reasonable.

```
class Tpacket_list
{public: // functions that are available to code outside the class.
```

Your teacher seems to be working hard at disproving the usual wisdom about formatting. Most people figure that the exact formatting you choose is less important than using it consistently. This is one of the few I've seen that really does seem to make the code more difficult to read.

```
    // put the command line into the list.
    Tpacket_list(int param_index, string param) ;  
    void print_list() ; // print the list.
    Tpacket_list* find( string target) ;
    int    tell_id() ;
    string tell_payload() ;
```

The comment here is misleading at best. The code to put the command line into the list is elsewhere (somewhere down in `main`).

```
 protected:                //  Data in a class is normally hidden from other code.
    string payload ;       // C++ strings are classes so this is aggregation.
    int id ;               // Such strings are more powerful and easier to use
    Tpacket_list *next ;   //   than the older C string routines, also slower!
} ;
```

Here we have a real design problem. He's conflating two ideas that should be completely separate: a linked list, and a node *in* a linked list. To work at all well, a linked list nearly needs to separate the two:

```
class list {    
    struct Node { 
        int id;
        std::string param;
        Node *next;

        Node(int param_index, std::string const &p) :
            id(param_index), param(p)
        {}
    }

public:
    list(list const &);
    // ...
private:
    node *list_head;
};
```

In this case, a `node` is pretty much just dumb data; the list class has all the real "knowledge" of how to do useful things. Also note that in reality, this should almost certainly be a class template instead of an actual class. Instead of hard-coding an `int` and a `std::string` as the types of data being stored, we really want to make those template parameters so we can create a linked list holding any kind of data we want.

```
Tpacket_list *list_head ;  // Start of linked list, set to 1st item.
Tpacket_list *work_ptr ;   // Work pointer to work along list.
```

"Daddy, he defined a global!"
"Son, what have I told you about using language like that?"

```
//====== Class Body =========================================================

//------ Constructor gets called when the class is created. It puts in the
//       payload and sets up the chain of pointers.All this is hideen from
//       the user of the class.
```

I'll repeat the earlier comment about comments for emphasis: while (barely) acceptable under the circumstances, these would clearly have no place in real code.

```
Tpacket_list::Tpacket_list(int param_index, string param) 
{//--- save information for this parameter.
   id = param_index ;
   payload = param ;
   cout << "    Adding parameter # " << id << ", value = " << payload << endl ;
 //--- form list.
   next = list_head ;
   list_head = this ;
}
```

This code has quite a problems. First of all, you should generally prefer initializing the members in an initializer list:

```
Tpacket_list::Tpacket_list(int param_index, string param) :
    id(param_index),
    payload(param)
```

OTOH, per the earlier comment, this code should really be in Node::Node instead. From the viewpoint of the linked list, this code shouldn't be in a ctor at all. Following the usual conventions for C++, this would be a function named `push_front` (and it would normally only take *one* data type as the input -- to store an `int` and a `std::string`, we'd put those together into a struct of some sort -- an `std::pair`, if nothing else.

```
//------ Print the list.  Note how the function calls the print_list function
//       in the next item in the link list.
//       Function prints from the current link list item to the end.
void Tpacket_list::print_list()
{//---
   cout << "    id = " << id << ",  payload = " << payload << ", length " << payload.length() << " characters."<< endl ;
   if ( next != NULL) // if there is a next item, get it to print itself.
     next->print_list() ;
}
```

IMO, the very existence of this function is a problem. To print out the contents of a list, we really want to apply an algorithm (e.g., `std::copy`) to the list (or some subset thereof). To do that, our list should define `begin()` and `end()`, which return list iterators. The iterator type should define (at least) operator++ to traverse the list. In our case, the iterator type would be a fairly thin wrapper around a pointer to a node:

```
class list {
    class Node { /* ... */ };

    // warning: typing this in off the top of my head. It probably has at least a few
    // problems.
    class iterator {
        Node *pos;
    public:
        Node operator*() { return *pos; }
        iterator &operator++() { 
            if (NULL == pos)
                return NULL;
            pos = pos -> next;
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator==(iterator const &other) { 
            return pos == other.pos;
        }
    };
```

This way, when we want to print out a list, we can use the same algorithms (and idioms in general) that we can with any of the other containers in the standard library.

```
//------ Find item in the list.
Tpacket_list* Tpacket_list::find( string target)
{//---
   if ( payload == target)
      return ( this) ;          // return pointer to current object.
   if ( next == NULL)
      return( NULL) ;           // end of list, not match, return NULL.
   //--- if got here there is a valid next.
   return( next->find( target)) ;
}
```

Again, probably pointless -- instead of a `find` member function, provide a conforming iterator type so you use use `std::find` (among other things).

```
//------ Tell of internal data.
int    Tpacket_list::tell_id() 
 { return( id) ;
 }

string Tpacket_list::tell_payload()
 { return( payload) ;
 }
```

I can't say I *like* these much, but they're about the only thing so far that isn't obviously/blatantly wrong...

```
//====== Start program here =================================================

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) // argc = number strings on command line.
                                 // argv is array of strings each holding 
                                 //   a parameter.

{//--- Initialize link list with command parameters.
   cout << endl << "  Form link list of command line parameters." << endl ;
   list_head = NULL ;
   int i = 1 ;
   while ( i < argc)
    { new Tpacket_list(i, argv[i]) ;
      i++ ;
    }
```

Here we see the bad effects of the poor design. This code *claims* to create (and, incidentally, leak) `argc-1` separate `Tpacket_list`s. In reality, it creates a single linked list, because the ctor does an implicit `push_front` on the (singular) global linked list represented by the nasty global. For usability we clearly want something like this:

```
    linked_list<std::pair<int, std::string> > list;

    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++)
        list.push_back(std::make_pair(i, argv[i]));

 //--- print out the list.
   cout << "  Print paramters from head of list the end of list." << endl ;
   if ( list_head != NULL)
        list_head->print_list() ;
   else cout << "   List is empty." << endl ;
```

Then, to print out the list, we'd have code like:

```
if (list.empty())
    std::cout << "List is empty.\n";
else
    std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::pair<int, std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

and of course:

```
 //--- search for parameters
   cout << "  Find first 0 parameter (working last to first parameter, list head to tail)." << endl ;
   Tpacket_list *found ;
   if ( list_head != NULL)
     { found = list_head->find("0") ;
       if ( found != NULL)
            cout << "    Found target on parameter # " << found->tell_id()  << endl ;
       else cout << "    No \"0\" found." << endl ;
     }
```

...searching in the linked list would be done with `std::find` instead of writing our own (clumsy) imitation.

As a final note, since the linked list allocates Nodes dynamically, we almost certainly need to provide a dtor that will delete those nodes. We also want to either provide a copy ctor that will copy the nodes, or else declare the copy ctor privately<sup>1</sup> to prevent anybody from copying a linked list at all.

---

<sup>1</sup> In C++11, we could use the `=delete` syntax to remove it as well, but it may be a bit premature to teach that as normal C++ usage just yet.

Comment: Great explanation, I would vote more than once if I could

Comment: Can't fault any of your comments if this was production code. But this is code being used to teach concepts to people that have not learned all of them. The inclusion of `list_head` is an indication that this is not complete (otherwise your application can only have one list) and is being used as a work in progress that will be improved upon as more advanced techniques are introduced.

Comment: @Jerry: If he provides copy-ctor, he has to provide copy-assignment as well.

Comment: Some of the comments are vacuous but possibly useful to beginners.  Not "`Class Body`", however, that's just wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your indepth assessment of the code.  I had a feeling that some of it was pretty bad, especially the design!  I needed to be sure as to what exactly was wrong with it, so that I myself, don't learn incorrectly from it.  Unfortunately, this code is what we are supposed to use as a 'model'.

Thank you for your time.  I too wish that I could vote you up more than once!

Answer (score 3):

The code below is not perfect. But we have to take into consideration that we are trying to convey basic concepts to a group of people that do not understand the full scope of C++ yet. Thus certain shortcuts will be made on a class of this complexity. Over the course of a year you may re-visit this code and see incremental improvements as your class increases its knowledge of the language.

For example I have commented on places where I would expect to see streams/smart pointers/const corectnes/Iterators/exceptions. But it would be pointless to include these concepts into a program being taught to absolute beginners. You need to teach the concept then retrofit the code with the new concept.

---

#### Summary:

The code wraps functionality into a node object that should probably be contained in a higher level construct (like the list object). There are a few clues in the code that indicate that this is a work in progress to teach concepts (so we can forgive that).

Way to many comments for real code.
They clutter things up and make it hard to read (But OK since it is part of teaching course).

This is just lazy
Avoid `using namespace` if at all possible

```
using namespace std ;
```

> Data in a class is normally hidden from other code.C++ strings are classes so this is aggregation. Such strings are more powerful and easier to use than the older C string routines, also slower!

I disagree with the `slower`. C++ string may use a couple more bytes but if general usage will be quicker because the size if pre-computed (you would be surprised how many times the size of a C-string is re-computed).

```
class Tpacket_list
{public:
```

That is really ugly. Put the `public` on its own line (make it readable).

```
void print_list() ;
```

Print the list where? Usually when you print something you are printing to a stream (std::cout). Usually you want to make sure you can pass in a different type of stream so it can go to a file or be serialized to a string for transport. SO I would have expected a print statement to take a stream object so the stream could be printed.

Also in C++ objects are usually printed via the << operator. But it is acceptable to put a print method in the class to act as a helper for the operator. The stream operator may be something that will come latter in the course.

```
    Tpacket_list* find( string target) ;
```

Pointers are a really bad idea. They do not convey ownership of the returned object (so who is responsible for deleting them). I assume the problem is that if you can find the object you need a way to indicate that it was not contained and you can use NULL to indicate this. Containers in C++ usually return iterators on a find. A failure to find an element returns end() (which is an iterator to one passed the end of the container).

Also prefer to pass parameters by const reference (prevents an unnecessary copy).

```
    int    tell_id() ;
    string tell_payload() ;
```

Looks like the last three methods should all be marked const.
They all seem to be non mutating methods. Thus they are all const.

```
    protected:
```

Protected provides no protection (it does but it is an illusion that is easily pierced). Prefer to use private (especially in this case). By using public/protected you are including all these members in the public interface (this is an OO concept not a C++ concept) of the object. Anything in the public interface must be maintained in the future thus tightly binding you to this implementation.

```
    Tpacket_list *next ;
```

Combining business data and resource management into a single object breaks the [separation of concerns principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). By making your object do both resource management (handling the actions of a list) and business logic (packet data) you might be making it more compact but you are making the code more complex to handle this situation. As a result you will pay for your compact data with more code.

```
Tpacket_list *list_head ;  // Start of linked list, set to 1st item.
Tpacket_list *work_ptr ;   // Work pointer to work along list.
```

OK. I am going to ignore this and assume it is a work in progress. Otherwise your application can only have one list.

```
Tpacket_list::Tpacket_list(int param_index, string param)
{
    id = param_index ;
    payload = param ;
```

Prefer to use the initializer list.

```
void Tpacket_list::print_list()
{
    if ( next != NULL)
        next->print_list() ;
```

Recursion is a neat trick to teach for education purposes. But in industrial code prefer a loop here. Recursion has the potential of blowing your stack. A loop will always work no matter what the size of the list. Should be encapsulated in at a higher level (the owner of the list nodes).

Answer (score 2):

To say the truth, it's bad code, the comments are the only good thing, though they could be better. Here are some ways to improve your code:

- use multiple files: the declarations of the class and functions should be in .h, while the implementation should be in a separate file, it would be better also to put the main separately
- there is a lot of formatting to be done,

like for

```
if ( found != NULL)
            cout << "    Found target on parameter # " << found->tell_id()  << endl ;
       else cout << "    No \"0\" found." << endl ;
```

could be

```
if ( found != NULL)
     cout << "    Found target on parameter # " << found->tell_id()  << endl ;
else 
    cout << "    No \"0\" found." << endl ;
```

or even better

```
if ( found != NULL) {
            cout << "    Found target on parameter # " << found->tell_id()  << endl ;
} else {
    cout << "    No \"0\" found." << endl ;
}
```

so that you can add code later without any problem

Comment: Where in the world did you get the idea that C++ should use camel case?

Comment: I thought it is recommended, isn't it?

Comment: @Mansuro: Using the underscores in C++ is still very standard. See the Google style guide: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml  "Variable names are all lowercase, with underscores between words". This is what STL and Boost do, as well.

Comment: Sorry, I disagree. The comments are hands down the worst thing in this code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph it's true they are ugly, but since they are for teaching purposes I guess they could be acceptable

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>   // C++ IO library code to include.
#include <string>     // C++ string functions.
using namespace std ; // Use standard C++ names for functions.


//====== class declaration.

class Tpacket_list
{public: // functions that are available to code outside the class.
```

Better to put public on a line by itself

```
    // put the command line into the list.
    Tpacket_list(int param_index, string param) ;  
    void print_list() ; // print the list.
    Tpacket_list* find( string target) ;
    int    tell_id() ;
    string tell_payload() ;
```

tell? typically people use get, or no prefix. Using tell is odd.

```
 protected:                //  Data in a class is normally hidden from other code.
    string payload ;       // C++ strings are classes so this is aggregation.
    int id ;               // Such strings are more powerful and easier to use
    Tpacket_list *next ;   //   than the older C string routines, also slower!
} ;


Tpacket_list *list_head ;  // Start of linked list, set to 1st item.
Tpacket_list *work_ptr ;   // Work pointer to work along list.
```

Global variables are not recommended

```
//====== Class Body =========================================================

//------ Constructor gets called when the class is created. It puts in the
//       payload and sets up the chain of pointers.All this is hideen from
//       the user of the class.
```

You don't need to tell me that a constructor gets called when teh class is created. Anybody reading your code will know that. Your comment should really describe the meaning of the parameters not discussion of what is hidden from the user.

```
Tpacket_list::Tpacket_list(int param_index, string param) 
{//--- save information for this parameter.
   id = param_index ;
   payload = param ;
   cout << "    Adding parameter # " << id << ", value = " << payload << endl ;
 //--- form list.
   next = list_head ;
   list_head = this ;
```

Its usually better to manage the list outside of the class. Always putting ever element in a list is usually a bad idea.

```
}

//------ Print the list.  Note how the function calls the print_list function
//       in the next item in the link list.
//       Function prints from the current link list item to the end.
void Tpacket_list::print_list()
{//---
   cout << "    id = " << id << ",  payload = " << payload << ", length " << payload.length() << " characters."<< endl ;
   if ( next != NULL) // if there is a next item, get it to print itself.
     next->print_list() ;
}
```

This function is recursive, but that is not generally a good idea. It'll limit how many elements you can have in your list and be less efficent then an iterative solution.

```
//------ Find item in the list.
Tpacket_list* Tpacket_list::find( string target)
{//---
   if ( payload == target)
      return ( this) ;          // return pointer to current object.
```

You don't need parens for a return statement.

```
   if ( next == NULL)
      return( NULL) ;           // end of list, not match, return NULL.
   //--- if got here there is a valid next.
   return( next->find( target)) ;
}

//------ Tell of internal data.
int    Tpacket_list::tell_id() 
 { return( id) ;
 }

string Tpacket_list::tell_payload()
 { return( payload) ;
 }

//====== Start program here =================================================

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) // argc = number strings on command line.
                                 // argv is array of strings each holding 
                                 //   a parameter.

{//--- Initialize link list with command parameters.
   cout << endl << "  Form link list of command line parameters." << endl ;
   list_head = NULL ;
   int i = 1 ;
   while ( i < argc)
    { new Tpacket_list(i, argv[i]) ;
      i++ ;
    }
```

Use a for loop, not a while loop here.

```
 //--- print out the list.
   cout << "  Print paramters from head of list the end of list." << endl ;
   if ( list_head != NULL)
        list_head->print_list() ;
   else cout << "   List is empty." << endl ;

 //--- search for parameters
   cout << "  Find first 0 parameter (working last to first parameter, list head to tail)." << endl ;
   Tpacket_list *found ;
   if ( list_head != NULL)
     { found = list_head->find("0") ;
```

I recommend not putting the statement on the same line as {1

```
       if ( found != NULL)
            cout << "    Found target on parameter # " << found->tell_id()  << endl ;
       else cout << "    No \"0\" found." << endl ;
     }

   cout << endl ;
   return(0) ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, as a disclaimer, I don't code in C/C++, so I may critique some common practices that are considered acceptable as it's the norm.

Nevertheless, a few things stand out.

**Comments**

Comments should be used to describe why something is being done.  The code itself should be self-descriptive as to what it is doing.

`Tpacket_list *work_ptr ;   // Work pointer to work along list.`

For example, could this variable be renamed to make it self-descriptive?  Perhaps `*current_list_item`.  Perhaps something else that would eliminate the need for the comment.

**One File Per Class**

Generally speaking, you want one file per class.  I also believe it is common practice for C/C++ programs to have one file for the header and one for the code for that header.  Maybe something like `Tpacket_list.h` and `Tpacket_list.cpp`, as well as your `main.cpp`.

**Scope**

Why are your Tpacket_list variables protected?  Is there a reason they aren't private?

Also, list_head is declared in main, then freely accessed as a global variable within the Tpacket_list class.  Rather than do this, it is considered better practice to use Dependency Injection.  Pass this variable in to the class that requires access to it.

It will make your code far easier to maintain later.  It will also open up the possibility of unit testing your class.

**Random Thoughts**

- Can you simply return early if there is no list?
- Tpacket_list seems to be both the collection and the items of the collection.  Would splitting these concepts out make sense?  If the program remains small, I'm sure it's fine.  If it grows to be large, this will gain value.
- It's stylistic as to whether or not you use curly brackets around the contents of if-else statements however I would note that I've never seen someone make an error with them in place, yet I have seen mistakes where they were missing.